Find the number of Linear Extensions of a poset P
In a past exam paper of a module I am sitting, a Poset (partially ordered set) $P_n$ was defined as  consisting of the positive integer factors of $3 · 2
^{n−1}$
, with the
divisibility ordering. It asks to find the number of linear extensions for $P_n$ for all n. A similar question has been asked regarding the number of anti-chains, and I solved this using an inclusion exclusion argument, but I am unsure how to answer this question.
Any help / guidelines for the solution to this questions and questions like it from an exam setting would be appreciated!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Nice question!
The factors of of $3 \cdot 2^{n-1}$ can be divided into two chains with $n$ elements each:
$A = 1,2,2^2,…, 2^{n-1}$
$B = 3\cdot 1,3\cdot 2, 3\cdot 2^2,…, 3\cdot 2^{n-1}$
In any valid linear extension, the elements of $A$ must go from left to right. Same for $B$.
Moreover, the crucial observation is that in any prefix of a valid linear extension, the number of elements from $A$ must be at least the number of elements of $B$ in the prefix. Otherwise, we would have say $3\cdot 2^i$ before $2^i$ for some $i$ which is not ok in a linear extension.
So we can build a linear extension using a Dyck path. For example, $A, A, B, B, A,…$ would correspond to linear extension $1,2,3,3\cdot 2,2^2,…$. Note that this is a bijection, any linear extension corresponds to a Dyck path, and conversely any Dyck path is a linear extension. So the answer is the number of Dyck paths with $2n$ elements, which is the $n$th Catalan number.

Thank you for your answer! The idea of Dyck paths did not appear on my course. I am wondering if you would know of a way to prove that portion of the proof using enumeration?

@bsch702702 Did you cover the Catalan numbers in your course. There are numerous ways to introduce them in an enumeration course, and the main idea is just having a bijection to whatever structure you defined the Catalan numbers on.
